# Diff in Diff: wrong control group or wrong method?

Tags: least-squares, causality, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, case-control-study

I want to identify the causal effect of renewable energy targets on the environmental policy stringency index (I got it from OECD) for EU countries. My hypothesis is that by setting a renewable energy (RE) target, environmental policies will have to respond in order to accomplish it (as it happened).
I am thinking to use a Diff-in-Diff approach, where my treatment is the RE target (in 2009), my treatment group are EU countries and my control group is Canada, USA, Japan and Korea.
The Diff-in-Diff approach requires that the control and treatment groups have similar trends for the variable of interest in the pre-treatment period, as it seems to be:
EPS value in the EU treatment group
[image: eps in EU treatment group]

[image: log of eps in EU treatment group]

[image: eps in control group]

[image: log of eps in control group]

Below, you have the two graphs together, also for the logs of the environmental policy stringency index:

[image]
[image]

Now, the problem: as you can see the eps follow similar paths in both the control and treatment group. Basically, the countries in the control group did not receive the treatment, but for some other reasons (other policies? other environmental targets etc) they also increased their EPS.
This is of course not helpful if the control group is going to be used as the counterfactual of my EU treatment group.
What would you suggest? Should I change the control group or research design?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: You don't need to look at whether you have parallel trends _within_ your treatment/control groups. You need parallel trends _between_ control and treatment. Could you plot the average trends in control and treatment (two lines) in the same chart?

Comment: @AdriàLuz yes, sorry, i did not think that it was less easy to understand by looking at it in different pictures. i have just edited the post!

Comment: The trends are similar *between* groups but you’re concerned why? I would be very happy with that finding given the methodology you’re adopting.

Comment: @ThomasBilach im concerned because my outcome variable in the control group follows a similar pattern wrt the treatment group. basically environmental policy stringency has been growing everywhere in the last 20 years, so even without my treatment the control group experiences a growth in the outcome variable